# How to remove in GitLab the tab Monitor -> Service Desk

Tags: gitlab, cicd

*What I am trying to achieve:*

In GitLab version 16, on the left panel, there is a panel Monitor -> Service Desk.

Please see screenshot.

[image]

How to remove this from the left panel?

*What I tried:*

I went to settings and managed to remove the other Monitor items (alerts, etc...)

*Issue:*

It seems there is no way to remove this Monitor -> Service Desk

*Question:*

We do not need this "Service Desk" and would like to simply remove it. How to do so?

Comment: I'm also interested in this, and have spent hours looking for how to disable it. I would expect it to disappear once I disabled it in `gitlab.rb`

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, it seems like there is not a way to get rid of it.

I created an issue to raise this with the Gitlab Team: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/426834